# Travis-CI and PostgreSQL: psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, travis-ci

I'm trying to get a PostgreSQL 12 Database for my Travis-CI build. I've been trying for hours. I've looked at the other threads on Travis-CI Community and on StackOverFlow. But I've made no progress and it keeps failing.

I'm using `dist: focal` so it has PostgreSQL 12.2. So I don't need to mess with `addons: postgres: '12'` and `apt: ...`
The `psql --version` command works, but the `psql -c 'create database ...` command does not.

If I remove the `psql -c 'create database ...` command, my application fails to start due to the missing Database, with

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException at ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException at Net.java:-2
```

Yes, I've read the Travis [Database Setup](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#postgresql) Documentation.
The link to the Travis build is: [lukegjpotter/pokemon-team-building-tools/jobs/480144598](https://travis-ci.com/github/lukegjpotter/pokemon-team-building-tools/jobs/480144598).
Please Help.

The relevant lines in my travis.yml file is as follows:

```
language: java
os: linux
dist: focal
jdk:  oraclejdk13
services:
  - postgresql
before_script:
  - cp config/database.yml.travis config/database.yml
  - psql --version
  - psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres
env: DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/travis_ci_test
```

The relevant lines in my build output is as follows:

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.5 (Ubuntu 12.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)

$ psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
The command "psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres" failed and exited with 2 during .
```

Regards,
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues is the Port Number in the error message.

```
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

On some distros and postgres versions, Postgres runs on port `5432`.
On `dist: focal` and `services: postgresql` the port is `5433`. The `psql` command uses port `5432`.
To solve this, you need to add the `-p 5433` to the `psql` command:

```
$ psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE travis_ci_test;' -U postgres -p 5433
```

This will then give a new error;

```
psql: error: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
The command "psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE travis_ci_test;' -U postgres -p 5433" failed and exited with 2 during .
```

But that is an error for another day.